# I need to convert my mongo collection into array of object to array of string

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

i have a collection in mongo is something like that

```
 profile": {
        "carIds": [
            ObjectId("5b21069649161a3806685f1e")
        ]
 }
```

i want to migrate it into array of object

```
profile: {
        carIds: [
            {
           id: ObjectId("5b21069649161a3806685f1e"),
             }] }
```

I need a query to convert array of strings into array of objects

Comment: Do you want to update into database or want the output like that?

Comment: I want to update in my db

Comment: All the documents ?

Comment: yes where the carIds key exists